# Python use command word in the function

Tags: python

I am new in Python.

This is part of python web service(Flask) code.

The function login uses command as its parameter,however; I don't see any other classes to call login function.

My question is :
What does command do here?

```
import MySQLdb as mydb

def login(command):
    command = command[1:]
    command = command[:-1]
    command = command[15:]
    i = 0
    while command[i] != ',':
        i = i + 1
    username = command[:i - 1]
    command = command[i + 17:]
    i = 0
    while command[i] != ',':
        i = i + 1
    password = command[:i - 1]
    return queryUser(username, password)

def queryUser(username, password):
    sdb = mydb.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',passwd='1',db='testDB')
    query = sdb.cursor()
    query.execute("""SELECT user_id FROM user_info WHERE user_id = %s AND user_password = %s""", (username,password,))
    if query.fetchone() is not None:
        query.close()
        sdb.close()
        return 'true'
    else:
        query.close()
        sdb.close()
        return 'false: Invalid username and password'
```

Comment: It's a string, and it looks like it contains some information with comma separators.

Comment: If you don't see anything calling `login()`, I suspect it's called automatically by Flask. The Flask documentation should explain what's in the `command` parameter.

Comment: This appears to be a hideous implementation of a kind of `split` for a string that contains the username and the password with some other information. Do you have an example of this function being called?

Comment: Why don't you put `print(command)` at the beginning of the function to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a function imported by another module somewhere else in the code base (or possibly by Flask itself automatically). The code is horribly unpythonic but from what I can tell, `command` is a string that contains a username and a password, separated by a comma like this:

```
login('????????????????awd,?????????????????1234cats,?????') → queryUser('awd', '1234cats')
```

Comment: More like: `login('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,c')` -> `queryUser('aa', 'bb')`

Comment: There must be more than just the username and password in it. Notice `command = command[15:]` and `command = command[i+17:]`

Comment: probably true, the function assumes a lot about the string and it's hard to tell. It extracts two fields from a string where somehow the other fields have fixed length

Answer (score 0):

Command would be rewritten from this

```
command = command[1:]
command = command[:-1]
command = command[15:]
```

to this:

```
command[16:-1]
```

if you want to split up a string by a comma letter use:

```
my_list = command.split(',')
```

I think practicing with these 2 concepts will help you in your programming.  (Python is not like C).
Watch this for more looping details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o